# check two larger numbers out of three numbers

Tags: php

Given three numbers, how can I sum up just the biggest two and disregard the smallest one? From the example below the output would be the sum of `$one + $three`.

```
<?php
$one = 210;
$two = 20;
$three = 30;

if ($one>$two)
{
   if($one>$three)
      {echo "$one";}
   else
      {echo "$three";}
 }
else
{
if ($two>$three)
    {echo "$two";}

else
    {echo "$three";}
} 

?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 4):

I can't see the sum in your code snippet, but if you just want to sum the two largest of three numbers, as you say in the question, sum all three and subtract the minimum:

```
$sum = $one + $two + $three - min($one, $two, $three);
```

Comment: Did you understand what the OP wants? I couldn't. So I am asking you.

Comment: He says, that he wants to add up the two largest out of three numbers. He even gave an example: Given 210, 20 and 30, the expected result would be 210+30=240. But indeed, the aim of the code sample in the question is unclear to me.